# How disable/enable button with ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an input field and a button. It must be disable at start. When the input no blank is, the button is enable.

I use a ngModel to take the value of the input and a function (change) to start a function each time the input is changed.

Now I do a little if in the change function.

```
if(input !== ''){
//enable the button
}else{
//disable the button
}
```

Have you any idea how to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Just have a boolean variable in class:

```
isenabled:boolean=false;
```

Change function

```
if(input !== ''){
//enable the button
isenabled=true; 
}else{
//disable the button
isenabled=false;
}
```

In Html:

```
<button ion-button [disabled]="!isenabled"></button>
```

For changing classes:

```
<button ion-button [ngClass]="{class:isenabled,class2:!isenabled}"></button>
```

Check [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngClass)

Comment: It answers my question which was clumsily asked. But how can I add or remove a class using the same system? I need not a enable or disable the button, but have a link blue ou grey regarding to the context!

Comment: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token !, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 27 in [{isenabled: disableButton,!isenabled: